# Unmarshall into an interface type

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I expected below code to print an object of type struct `J`, however it prints a map object of type `map[string]interface{}`. I can feel why it acts like that, however when I run, reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind(), it returns `Struct`, so it kinda gives me the impression that `Unmarshal` method should return type `J` instead of a map. Could anyone enlighten me ?

```
type J struct {
    Text string
}

func main() {
    j := J{}
    var i interface{} = j

    js := "{\"Text\": \"lala\"}"


    json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &i)

    fmt.Printf("%#v", i)

}
```

Comment: I ran this, changing `fmt.Printf("%#v", i)` to `fmt.Printf("%v", reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind())` the output is: map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you're passing into `Unmarshal` is not `*J`, you're passing in an `*interface{}`.

When the `json` package reflects what the type is of the pointer it received, it sees `interface{}`, so it then uses the default types of the package to unmarshal into, which are

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

There is almost never a reason to use a pointer to an interface. If you find yourself using a pointer to an interface, and you don't know *exactly* why, then it's probably a mistake. If you want to unmarshal into `J`, then pass that in directly. If you need to assign that to an intermediary interface, make sure you use a pointer to the original value, not a pointer to its interface.

http://play.golang.org/p/uJDFKfSIxN

```
j := J{}
var i interface{} = &j

js := "{\"Text\": \"lala\"}"

json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), i)

fmt.Printf("%#v", i)
```

Comment: Ye i kinda mentioned it in my question, that I know that. However reflect.TypeOf(i) will tell us that the type is actually main.J. And the kind of it is Struct. So it makes no sense for it to return us a map.

Comment: @OzumSafa: except that you're not passing in `i` to `Unmarshal`, you're passing in `&i`, so the type is `*interface{}`, not `J`. Even if it were the case that the json package dug down to find `J`, you wouldn't have a pointer to `j`, so it couldn't unmarshal into it.

Comment: Ahhhh, enlightment is real. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior: instead of giving `json.Unmarshal` a pointer to a properly typed place in memory you give it a pointer to a place in memory with type `interface{}`. It can essentially store anything in there under the type the JSON defines, so it does just that.

See it like this:

1. `Unmarshal` gets a place to store the data `v` with type `interface{}`
2. `Unmarshal` detects a map encoded as JSON
3. `Unmarshal` sees that the target type is of type `interface{}`, creates a go map from it and stores it in `v`

If you would have given it a different type than `interface{}` the process would have looked like this:

1. `Unmarshal` gets a place to store the data `v` with type `struct main.J`
2. `Unmarshal` detects a map encoded as JSON
3. `Unmarshal` sees that the target type is `struct main.J` and begins to recursively fit the data to the type

The main point is, that the initial assignment

```
var i interface{} = j
```

is completely ignored by `json.Unmarshal`.

Comment: Your answer is also awesome, but the answer above is more to the point. But thank you.